# How to make a variable dependent on other?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to relate two variables in kotlin for understanding purposes.

Here's what I'm trying to do.

I want `var impact` dependent on `var lives`. as in every occurrence of `var lives` should contain 70 units of `var impact`.

Please guide me how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use property delegate, it fires off every time value of the property changes. Using delegate, you can change `lives` property dependent on `impact` new value:

```
var lives: Int = 0
var impact: Int by Delegates.observable(0) { property, oldValue, newValue ->
    // add your logic here to react on changes of `impact` variable
    lives = 70 * newValue
}
```

`Delegates.observable()` is a built-in delegate from Kotlin standard library.

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to use a property without a backing field for impact:

```
var lives = 0
val impact get(): Int {
    // do something
    return lives * 5 // impact depends on lives
}
```

This way you do not change `impact` reactively, like in Sergey's answer, but rather you get a value dependant on `lives` if you access `impact`.